# Unresolved symbols in DirectX12 ToolKit project only for x64

Tags: directxtk

I have a dxtk12 project that I worked on earlier. Currently I am using another Windows architecture - x64 and version of VS - 2019 (earlier - x86 and vs2017).

I tried to compile my project for x64 release but got linker errors:

```
1>DeviceResources.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol D3D12CreateDevice
1>DeviceResources.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol CreateDXGIFactory2
1>DirectXTK12.lib(SpriteBatch.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol D3D12SerializeRootSignature
1>DirectXTK12.lib(ResourceUploadBatch.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol D3D12SerializeRootSignature
1>DirectXTK12.lib(EffectCommon.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol D3D12SerializeRootSignature
1>C:\Users\okuma\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\simulation\x64\Release\simulation.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
```

When I switch build option to x86 release all compiled successfully.

I tried to add `#pragma comment(lib, "RuntimeObject.lib")`, it didn't help.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Those symbols are in `d3d12.lib`. Most likely you do not have all the same settings in your `x64` configuration that you do in your `x86`.

In the Project Properties dialog, select the x64 platform in the combolist and then "All configurations" in the Configuration list.

Under the Linker make sure your "Additional Dependencies" include:

```
d3d12.lib;dxgi.lib;dxguid.lib
```

See [directx-vs-templates](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).

Comment: Hmm, including libraries You mentioned didn't help - still the same issue.

Comment: Perhaps I can just replace `Direct3DWin32Game.vcxproj` with my file?

Comment: You could create a fresh instance of the template, and them move your code files over as well.